# Translate along world axis after rotation in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm just beginning to learn Three.js and 3D programming in general. I have a camera that is rotated 45 degrees 'down' around x-axis. When I translate after rotating, the camera only moves along its local axes. How can I get it to move along the world x and z axes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
camera.position.x += delta;
camera.position.z += delta;
```

Comment: So camera.translateX(delta) isn't the same as camera.position.x += delta?

Comment: No, they are not. The best thing for you to do is to look at the source code so you can see exactly what `translateX` does.